# Intersection of two fasta files using python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, intersection, biopython, seq

I have two big fasta files - their structures are different (shown below) but the headers (start with @) for the reads are the same in both files:

file1

```
>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:12990:1333
AAAACCCC

>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:21652:2374
AAAAGGGG

>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:21652:2366
AGGGGGTT
```

file2

```
>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:12990:1333
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAGATCTCGCCC

>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:21652:2374
AGATCTCGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

>MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:21652:2366                  
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

I made a dictionary from the `headers` (key) and `reads` (value) of file1 using the script:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

dict={}
with open ('index2.fasta', 'r') as file1:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(file1, 'fasta'):
        dict[str(record.id)] = str(record.seq)
```

What I did was I looped over the reads in file2 and if the `'AGATCTCG'` string was inside reads, I kept those read's headers in a list.

Now what I have a problem with is I want to make a sub-file of file2 based on the `dictionary` and the `list`. If item of my list exist as key in my dictionary and if the value is `'AAAACCCC'` then the output should be `MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:12990:1333` BUT I get both `MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:12990:1333` and `MN00153:75:000H37WNG:1:12106:21652:2374`

```
ATTACTCG_ids=[]
with open ('Read1.fasta', 'r') as file2:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(file2, 'fasta'):
        if 'AGATCTCG' in record.seq:
            ATTACTCG_ids.append(record.id)
            for i in ATTACTCG_ids:
                if dict.get(i) == 'AAAACCCC':
                    final = record.format('fasta')
                    print(final)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your headers don't start with `>` so this is not FASTA.  `@` is like FASTQ header (but without the quality scores etc.) You appear to have a mangled file format and I'm surprised if Biopython or any other non-custom module parses it correctly

Comment: I just fixed it thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the accumulated ids list is iterated over each time.  You might just check each record separately. Perhaps something like this.

```
with open ('Read1.fasta', 'r') as file2:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(file2, 'fasta'):
        if 'AGATCTCG' in record.seq and dict.get(record.id) == 'AAAACCCC':
            final = record.format('fasta')
            print(final)
```